# How to use sound effects with animations done using Kineticjs

Tags: javascript, audio, kineticjs

I want to apply some sound effects on Kineticjs's animations.
Is that possible to have sound effects with KineticJS or I have to use some other JS library.

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Kineticjs only helps to work with canvas.

So you have to use other library. Look at http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS